# How do I initialize the base `tuple` when deriving from `typing.Tuple`?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

According to [the docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-generic-types-as-base-classes), "built-in generic types .. are valid both as types and as base classes."  It gives an example deriving from `Dict[str, List[Node]]`.

However, when I try this with `Tuple[int, int]`, the constructor doesn't forward properly.  For example:

```
from typing import Tuple

class MyTuple(Tuple[int, int]):
    def hello(self):
        print("hello: " + str(len(self)))

MyTuple([1, 2]).hello()
```

prints `hello: 0`.  If I derive from the builtin `tuple` instead, it prints `hello: 2`.

How can I initialize the base `tuple` object when deriving from `Tuple[int, int]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types in the `typing` module are not really meant to be directly instantiated: they're supposed to be used as static type hints in annotations.

But if you really need to, you can override `__new__()` to return a tuple:

```
class MyTuple(Tuple[int, int]):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return tuple(*args, **kwargs)

print(MyTuple('abc'))  # -> ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

This will create plain tuple objects every time you call `MyTuple()`. If instead you want the objects to be instances of your class:

```
class MyTuple(Tuple[int, int]):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

print(MyTuple('abc'))  # -> ('a', 'b', 'c')
print(type(MyTuple('abc')))  # -> __main__.MyTuple
```

This works because `typing.Tuple` is a subclass of `tuple`.

Note that calling `super().__new__()` would not work, because `typing.Tuple` (and other generic types) discard the arguments that you pass to them. You have to "short-circuit" by calling `tuple.__new__()` directly.

Comment: thanks.  Certainly, specifying the types of a generic base class is a corner case, but the docs I linked and quoted make it pretty clear that deriving from the built-in generic types is how you're supposed to do it.  If I derive directly from tuple, mypy complains that the elements of my tuples are of type Any.

Thanks for the suggestion of using `__new__`, I hadn't thought of that.  However, in my use case I'm adding methods and other fields; that doesn't work if I have `__new__` return a tuple, rather than an instance of my class.

Any other suggestions?